# Why my function returns promises even if I use async-await [react]? I'm using signal (@preact/signal-react)

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently working on a React application where I'm using the @preact/signal-react library to manage signals. I've noticed that even though I'm using async-await in my functions, they still return promises instead of resolving to the actual data.

I expected the fetchData function to resolve the promise and set the value of the signal, but it seems like it's still returning a promise.

```
import { signal } from "@preact/signals-react";
import { FetchAnimeMovieData, FetchPopularData, FetchRecentReleaseData, FetchTopAiringData } from "../functions/AnimeDataFetcher";
function CategoryPage() {
    const recentUpdate = signal(fetchData(FetchRecentReleaseData));
    const topAiring = signal(fetchData(FetchTopAiringData));
    const Popular = signal(fetchData(FetchPopularData));
    const animeMovies = signal(fetchData(FetchAnimeMovieData));
    const displayAnime = new signal();

    async function fetchData(fetchDataFunction){
        try {
            const jsonData = await fetchDataFunction(1);
            return jsonData;
            
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
    console.log(recentUpdate);
    {/*
        Object { v: Promise { "pending" }, i: 0, n: undefined, t: undefined }
                i: 0
                n: undefined
                t: Object { i: 0, S: {…}, p: undefined, … }
                v: Promise { <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: {…} }
                <state>: "fulfilled"
                <value>: Object { currentPage: 1, hasNextPage: true, results: (20) […] }
                <prototype>: Promise.prototype { … }
    */}
    return ( <>
        <div className="container">
            <h1 className="heading">Categories</h1>
            <div className="container">   
                <button>Recent Update</button>
                <button>Top Airing</button>
                <button>Anime Movies</button>
                <button>Popular</button>
            </div>
            {JSON.stringify(recentUpdate)}
            {recentUpdate?.value?.results?.map((item)=>(
                <p key={item.id}>{item.name}</p>
            ))}            
        </div>
    </> );
}

export default CategoryPage;
```

Additional Information:

```
I've made sure that fetchDataFunction is a function that returns a promise.
I've imported signal correctly from @preact/signal-react.
I'm using React for my application.
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, and I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: That it how promises work. Nevertheless you wait inside the function you need to to it outside as well. As soon as you dive into the async universe you need to stay there.

Comment: `I've noticed that even though I'm using async-await in my functions, they still return promises` async/await doesn't eliminate promises, just the opposite. By adding `async` to a function, you are **causing** that function to return a promise. It just lets you write your promise code using `await`'s instead of `.then`'s. I'm not too familiar with signals, but the standard react approach for loading data would be to put your fetching code in a `useEffect`, then set state once the data arrives. So i assume you'd do something similar, just update the signal when the data arrives.

Comment: Please do note, you cannot use `signal` inside of a functional component and expect a stable reference. You need to use `useSignal` in that case. We state this on our docs: https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/signals#signalinitialvalue